# Device enrollment fails, error: server certificate is invalid

Tags: ipad, osx-server, mobile-device-management

I have an Xserve running 10.7.2 Server fully patched today.

We have a valid SSL from GoDaddy installed. 
Lion's firewall is off, hardware firewall is not blocking any traffic.

From an iPad I can access the profile manager through the webpage https://mydomain.com/profilemanager and log in successfully.  I can install the Trust Profile successfully.

When I try enroll the device it gives me this error:

The server certificate for "https://mydomain.com/devicemanagement/api/device/ota_service" is invalid

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved.  When installing the SSL cert from GoDaddy in Lion server there are two items that need to take place outlined in [GoDaddy's guide for OS X Server 10.6](http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/5722):

1. Install Intermediate Chain
2. Install Certificate

The Intermediate Chain had not been completed and thus the Certificate was from showing as coming from an unsigned authority. Once the Intermediate Chain had been installed I was able to successfully enroll the device.

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue (including Godaddy Cert). The problem is that after reading this, I installed the intermediate chain cert, rebooted the box, and am still having issues. I **CAN** enroll my Macbook Pro, but I can't enroll my iOS devices (iPhone and iPad). Thoughts?